# Создать копию InputStream

Tags: java, потоки-данных

Есть код, в котором надо создать копию потока. Я никогда раньше не сталкивался с подобной задачей.
Дело в том, что этот поток мне надо проанализировать, ну и только после прочитать. Выкладываю проблемный кусочек кода:

```
import java.io.*;  
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.jar.JarFile;
import java.util.zip.*; 

public class InputZip{

    private ZipEntry entry;
    private ZipInputStream zipInput;

    public InputZip(String zipName) throws IOException
    {
        zipInput = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(zipName), Charset.defaultCharset());

        while ((entry = zipInput.getNextEntry()) != null) {
            InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(zipInput);
            InputStreamReader in2 = new InputStreamReader(zipInput); // Бесполезный
            InputStreamReader in3 = new InputStreamReader(zipInput);// Бесполезный

            analiz(in);

            Scanner scan = new Scanner(zipInput);
            String s = scan.nextLine(); // Исключение! Поток уже использован :(

            zipInput.closeEntry();
        }
        zipInput.close();
    }

    private void analiz(InputStreamReader b) throws IOException
    { 
        //Анализ потока (полное прочтение) 
    }
}
```

Нужно получить копию `zipInput`.

Comment: дай весь код ( http://ideone.com/ )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

InputStreamReader устроен так, что прочитать из него можно только один раз. Если данные надо обрабатывать дважды, то лучше воспользоваться BufferedReader или считать данные в массив и сформировать пару потоков, читающих из него.

**UPDATE:** Примитивный пример повторного чтения из буферизированного потока

```
import java.io.*;

public class Main {
    private static boolean analyze(BufferedReader br) throws IOException {
        br.mark(1000);
        String line = br.readLine();
        if(line != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
            br.reset();
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static void main(final String args[]) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("test.txt"));
        if(analyze(br))
            System.out.println(br.readLine());
        else
            System.err.println("ERROR!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Можно пожалуйста пример с BufferedReader

Comment: @sair обновил ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Ну так вы получаете объект ссылающийся на файл внутри, но читаете все равно сам zip-файл.
Используйте этот метод:

```
  InputStream is = zip.getInputStream(entry);
  InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
```

Вот [пример](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/java.util.zip/ZipFile/Java_ZipFile_getInputStream_ZipEntry_entry_.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Возможно для вашей задачи анализа потока стоит вместо копирования потока делать анализ во время обработки. Посмотрите в сторону FilterInputStream, суть в переопределении методов inputStream в которые добавляется необходимый вам анализ

Comment: Я все бы отдал что бы сделать все за раз но если анализ даст не тот результат то второй поток будет уже об этом знать и сделает все правильно...Я пока что решил эту задачу простым созданием файла наполнением значениями этого потока и после открытия двух FileInputStream все решаю...но это очень ресурсоемкий вариант по этому мне интересно предложение Sergey Gornostaev